# How can I get a sharp logo in my website?

Tags: png, file-format, jpg, visual-artifacts

When I upload my logo in png, it's coming with a pixelated white edge. When I send in jpeg, it's not sharp enough. How should I do it?

Comment: You've provided practically no information whatsoever. Upload where? What's the original format of the logo? What's the size of the logo? What's the size displayed after you upload?

Answer (score 4):

If you have the logo vector file...you could export as .SVG.
Have a look here:
https://css-tricks.com/using-svg

It will look the same across all sizes and users devices.

Answer (score 1):

What is the resolution of your image and what's the size of your element? I had a similar issue in the past although my image had great quality. Save as `300dpi` and use a very high resolution i.e. `1200px - 720px` and PNG of course as it tends to work better for sharp edges. However, I'm not sure if using a very high res is the best solution but thats how I solved my problem and didn't see any noticeable downsides.

[Read more about Image Compression](http://www.webreference.com/dev/graphics/compress.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should try designing your logo on a canvas double the size of the original height and width of your logo. Once complete the design, just go to File > Save For Web > Select the desired image format, give in the original height and width of your logo and click on the save button.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have saved it as an 8 bit png, or it's been cut out of a white background poorly. Best is to save as an svg. If you can't do that then a 32 bit png with transparency.

Note, if you are scaling the image down in the browser then some browsers will perform better than others. Ideally use svg!

Comment: Hi Twistedonion, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!